# Using print instead of sprintf with %s and % and multiple string substitution arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, syntax, printing

In the following ruby code, the output becomes: "x y"

```
x = "x %s"
y = "y"
z = "z"
print x % y %z
```

The %z is ignored.

I want the output to be "x y z".

**To understand the possibilities and limitations of the syntax of Ruby, I want to use only the print command and the %s and % flags**. I know how to do this using sprintf but I want to know if there's a way to do it with just the 'print' command.

So I tried adding a second %s to the definition of the variable 'x':

```
x = "x %s %s"
y = "y"
z = "z"
print x % y %z
```

But I got this error:

```
in `%': too few arguments (ArgumentError)
```

With sprintf you could do this:

```
x = "x %s %s"
y = "y"
z = "z"
print (sprintf(x, y, z))
```

The output would be what I wanted:

```
x y z
```

But that's just too easy.

***Is there a way to do this with just 'print' (not sprintf) and without using #{} or combining y and z into an array as [y,z]?***

Comment: You seem to have a lot of restrictions for a simple print, maybeif you elaborate a little more on the real problem, yo might get some better help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually understand what you want to do, but:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = "x %s"
=> "x %s"
irb(main):002:0> y = "y %s"
=> "y %s"
irb(main):003:0> z = "z"
=> "z"
irb(main):004:0> print x % y % z
x y z=> nil
```

and:

```
irb(main):006:0> x = "x %s %s"
=> "x %s %s"
irb(main):007:0> y = "y"
=> "y"
irb(main):008:0> z = "z"
=> "z"
irb(main):009:0> x % [y,z]
=> "x y z"
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use an array [y,z] - although it works also.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print "x #{y} #{z}"`.

I could not find much [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005993) easily with Google... however here are some pages where this usage is demonstrated:

http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_expressions.html

http://linuxgazette.net/issue81/ramankutty.html

http://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Ruby

Comment: So you can't avoid using the #{} notation?

Comment: i don't know. i think i better question is "why avoid using the #{} notation?".

Comment: To understand the possibilities and limitations of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The consensus seems to be that you can't avoid using the #{} substitution syntax. And the % notation only seems to work if you use an array [y,z] to combine the two variables into a single unit.

What I really wanted, though was some way to do this:

print x % y, z

without combining the y and z variables into one.

Perhaps this is not possible and you either have to:

1. Use #{} substitution
2. Combine y and z into an array and then call print x % [y,z]
3. Use sprintf like this: print (sprintf(x, y, z))

and define x as:

x = "x %s %s"

Answer (score 0):

Might this be what you want?:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = "x %s %s"
=> "x %s %s"
irb(main):002:0> y = "y"
=> "y"
irb(main):003:0> z = "z"
=> "z"
irb(main):004:0> print x % [y,z]
x y z=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to use an array [y,z] - although it works also.